# ¿ Cómo comparar elementos de un array?

Tags: php

Necesito comparar los elementos de mi array

```
$array_sin_nombre
```

Esta array contiene 12 elementos:

```
Array ( [0] => Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_No [1] => Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_No [2] => Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_No [3] => Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_Si [4] => Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_Si [5] => Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_Si [6] => Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_No [7] => Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_No [8] => Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_No [9] => Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_Si [10] => Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_Si [11] => Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_Si )
```

Si un elemento esta repetido entonces me tiene que saltar un mensaje de error, he intentado hacerlo con un for pero me da error.

```
for ($i=0; $i <$longitude_de_array_sin_nombre ;$i++) { 
        if ($array_sin_nombre[$i] == $array_sin_nombre[$i+1]) {
            echo "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor pon un ejemplo de la estructura de tu array para poder dar una respuesta basada en la realidad de los datos. [Puedes editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/205356/edit) agregando esa información faltante. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar las funciones que ya vienen en php, y finalmente el array que te devuelve si tiene es mayor que cero,  es que había valores repetidos. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php.

Si quieres hacerlo a mano tendrás que llevar 2 for.
for i = 0 y el segundo for es for j = i + 1.

Un saludo.

Comment: Pero la función array_intersect neceisto dos arrays, yo solo tengo una.

Comment: Pedro, ese tipo de ediciones como la que pusiste no son aceptadas en el sitio. Se considera *"destruccion de contenido util"*. Si tienes problemas con tu pregunta, contacta con un moderador pulsando en reportar > necesito internvencion de un moderador. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto. Por ejemplo:

#### ▸ Usando `array_flip`

El código se puede simplificar haciendo esto por ejemplo:

```
$msg= (count($arr) === count(array_flip($arr))) ? "mensaje por defecto o nada" : "error";
echo $msg;
```

---

#### ▸ Usando `array_unique`

```
$msg= (count($arr) === count(array_unique($arr))) ? "mensaje por defecto o nada" : "error";
echo $msg;
```

En ambos procedimientos se usa un operador ternario para asignar un mensaje según el caso.

---

#### ▸ Código de prueba completo ...<kbd>[VER DEMO](https://rextester.com/STO79699)</kbd>

```
$arrNoError=array ( 
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_Si"
                   );

$msg= (count($arrNoError) === count(array_flip($arrNoError))) ? "mensaje por defecto o nada" : "error";
echo $msg.PHP_EOL;

$msg= (count($arrNoError) === count(array_unique($arrNoError))) ? "mensaje por defecto o nada" : "error";
echo $msg.PHP_EOL;

$arrError=  array ( 
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Hombre,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_No",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Rubio,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_Si",
                     "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Pelirrojo,Gafas_Si"
                   );

$msg= (count($arrError) === count(array_flip($arrError))) ? "mensaje por defecto o nada" : "error";
echo $msg.PHP_EOL;

$msg= (count($arrError) === count(array_unique($arrError))) ? "mensaje por defecto o nada" : "error";
echo $msg.PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
mensaje por defecto o nada
mensaje por defecto o nada
error
error
```

---

**Fuente:**

- Respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3145607/5587982)  en Stackoverflow en inglés. La más rápida parece ser la primera opción.

---

#### ▸ Otra posibilidad

Si interesa saber cual(es) son los valores repetidos, se puede usar algo como esto:

```
$arrDiff=array_diff_key( $arrError , array_unique( $arrError ) );
$msg=(!$arrDiff) ?  "mensaje por defecto o nada" : "error";
```

Aquí se crea un nuevo elemento (`$arrDiff`)  que contendrá los valores que fueron encontrados repetidos:

```
var_dump($arrDiff);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(1) {
  [11]=>
  string(31) "Sexo_Mujer,Pelo_Moreno,Gafas_Si"
}
```

Comment: Difícil hacer una respuesta más completa y más fácil de entender. +1 de camino.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar dos bucles `for` anidados para comprobarlo, de manera que el primer `for` se encargue de recorrer el array y el segundo `for` de recorrer el array en cada elemento del anterior bucle.

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
    for ($j=0;$j<count($array);$j++) {
        if ($array[$i] == $array[$j] && $i!=$j) {
            echo "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Además se necesita la condición de que el elemento en la posición `$i` y la posición `$j` sean diferentes para no compararse consigo mismo.

Te en cuenta que a la salida se imprimirán dos errores por cada coincidencia, ya que cumplirá el condicional, en el caso de una coincidencia, cuando el primero es igual al segundo y cuando el segundo es igual al primero.

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145607/php-check-if-an-array-has-duplicates) en el sitio en ingles la solución seria algo tan simple como esto:

```
function has_dupes($array) {
    $dupe_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if (++$dupe_array[$val] > 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre la siguiente solución, por lo que veo, no te funciona porque el $i+1 llega a uno más del largo que tiene el array.
Propongo la siguiente solución:

```
for ($i=0; $i <$longitude_de_array_sin_nombre ;$i++) { 
    for($j=0;$j<$longitude_de_array_sin_nombre;$j++){        
        if($j != $i){
            if ($array_sin_nombre[$i] == $array_sin_nombre[$j]) {
                echo "error";
            }
        }
    }
}
```